# Parse JSON in shell

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

How can i do dictionary structure in shell? My aim is to generate random words. Ex. dirty fish, good book, ugly piano or pesante pasta, giallo cane... Its js code look like this

```
    words ={

"italian" :
{
    "name" :
            [
             "gatto", 
             "cane", 
             "pasta", 
             "telefono", 
             "libro"
             ],

    "adjective" : 
            [
             "pesante", 
             "sottile", 
             "giallo", 
             "stretto",      
             ]
},
"english" :
{
    "name" : 
            [
             "fish", 
             "book",
             "guitar",
             "piano",
             ],     
    "adjective" :
            [
              "dirty",
              "good",
              "ugly",
              "great",   
             ]
}}
```

I want this:

```
words[english][adjective][1]
>> good
```

Comment: Shell is the wrong language for this. Some shells support associative arrays, but few, if any, support nesting one array in another.

Comment: See my answer, `jq` is a shell tool and can parse JSON easyly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505/608639)

Answer (score 24):

The [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) itself can't store complicated Data Structures, but like most of the time in shell, you can use external tools, I demonstrate here 6 different solutions, all in Unix* like shells:

First, your `JSON` is broken, this is a valid version in `file.js` :

```
{
   "italian" : {
      "name" : [
         "gatto",
         "cane",
         "pasta",
         "telefono",
         "libro"
      ],
      "adjective" : [
         "pesante",
         "sottile",
         "giallo",
         "stretto"
      ]
   },
   "english" : {
      "name" : [
         "fish",
         "book",
         "guitar",
         "piano"
      ],
      "adjective" : [
         "dirty",
         "good",
         "ugly",
         "great"
      ]
   }
}
```

### Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```
$ jq '.english.adjective[1]' file.js
```

Output:

```
good
```

Playing with `jq` and `RANDOM` shell variable :

```
$ echo $(
    jq ".english.adjective[$((RANDOM%4))], .english.name[$((RANDOM%4))]" file.js
)
"great" "piano"
```

[jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), see the [tutorial](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/).

### Using [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino)

```
$ rhino<<EOF 2>/dev/null
hash = $(<file.js)
print(hash.english.adjective[1])
EOF
```

Output:

```
...
good
```

### Using [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)

```
$ node<<EOF
hash = $(<file.js)
console.log(hash.english.adjective[1])
EOF
```

Output :

```
good
```

### Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

Let's parse the DS in a perl command line :

```
$ perl -MJSON -0lnE '
    $words = decode_json $_;
    say $words->{english}->{adjective}->[1]
' file.js
```

Output:

```
good
```

### Using [python](/questions/tagged/python)

```
$ python<<EOF
import json
json_data = open('file.js')
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()
print(data['english']['adjective'][1])
EOF
```

Output:

```
good
```

### Using [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)

```
$ ruby<<EOF
require 'json'
file = File.read('file.js')
data = JSON.parse(file)
print(data['english']['adjective'][1])
EOF
```

Output:

```
good
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) 3.2+ without dependencies (such as jq, python, grep, etc.):

```
source <(curl -s -L -o- https://github.com/lirik90/bashJsonParser/raw/master/jsonParser.sh)
JSON=$(minifyJson "$JSON")
echo "Result is: $(parseJson "$JSON" english adjective 1)"
```

Output:

```
Result is: good
```

[Try it](https://replit.com/@lirik90/bashJsonParser-27127091).

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. If you find questions which are similar enough to warrant the same answer, leave a comment to suggest closing as duplicate.